# Смена цвета строк в таблице HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Я могу добавлять контакты в свою таблицу когда ввожу соответствующие данные в мои собственно говоря
соответствующие input'ы. Пытаюсь проверить select на выбор, и с помощью 'className' установить
разные цвета строк для разных выборов моего select'а, может кто то знает что я делаю не так,
потому что сейчас у меня для тех двух select'ов к которым я применяю стили - контакты
вообще не додаются, заранее спасибо!

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('click', dodajWiersz);

var lp = 1;

 function dodajWiersz() {
    var wiersz = document.createElement("tr");

     var liczba = document.createElement("td");
     liczba.innerHTML = lp;

     var imie = document.createElement("td");
     var val2 = document.getElementById("imie").value;
     imie.innerHTML = val2;

     var nazwisko = document.createElement("td");
     var val3 = document.getElementById("nazwisko").value;
     nazwisko.innerHTML = val3;

     var email = document.createElement("td");
     var val4 = document.getElementById("email").value;
     email.innerHTML = val4;

     var wiek = document.createElement("td");
     var val5 = document.getElementById("wiek").value;
     wiek.innerHTML = val5;

     var data = document.createElement("td");
     var val6 = document.getElementById("data").value;
     data.innerHTML = val6;

     var plec = document.createElement("td");
     var val7 = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
     plec.innerHTML = val7;

     var grupa = document.createElement("td");
     var val8 = document.getElementById("grupa").value;
     grupa.innerHTML = val8;
        switch(val8) {
            case "Rodzina":
                document.getElementById('tr').className = "RodzinaZielony";
                break;
            case 'Praca':
                document.getElementById('tr').className = "PracaOrange";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 

     wiersz.appendChild(liczba);
     wiersz.appendChild(imie);
     wiersz.appendChild(nazwisko);
     wiersz.appendChild(email);
     wiersz.appendChild(wiek);
     wiersz.appendChild(data);
     wiersz.appendChild(plec);
     wiersz.appendChild(grupa);

     var dodac = document.getElementById("tbd");
     dodac.appendChild(wiersz);
     lp = lp + 1;
 }
```

```css
tr.RodzinaZielony {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

tr.PracaOrange {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<table id="customersKontakty">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Liczba porządkowa</th>
       <th>Imię</th>
       <th>Nazwisko</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Wiek</th>
       <th>Data urodzenia</th>
       <th>Płeć</th>
       <th>Grupa</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbd">

  </tbody>
</table>
<element class="plabel">
  <br><br><br>
  <p class="plabell">Imię:<p><input type="text" id="imie"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Nazwisko:<p><input type="text" id="nazwisko"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Email:<p><input type="email" id="email"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Wiek:<p><input type="number" id="wiek"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Data urodzenia:<p><input type="date" id="data"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Płeć:
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mężczyzna"> Mężczyzna
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Kobieta"> Kobieta
    </p>
  </p>
  <p class="plabell">Grupa:
    <p>
      <select id="grupa">
        <option value="Rodzina">Rodzina</option>
        <option value="Przyjaciele">Przyjaciele</option>
        <option value="Praca">Praca</option>
        <option value="Znajomi">Znajomi</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </p>
</element>
<p align="center"><input type="button" value="Dodaj osobę" id="myBtn"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас нет эл-та с *id="tr"*, вместо этого следует использовать уже созданную переменную `wiersz` т.к. именно она содержит нужный эл-т.

Суммируя, Вам просто нужно заменить строку

```
document.getElementById('tr').className = "RodzinaZielony";
```

на

```
wiersz.classList.add("RodzinaZielony"); // wiersz.className = "RodzinaZielony";
```

и строку

```
document.getElementById('tr').className = "PracaOrange";
```

на

```
wiersz.classList.add("PracaOrange"); // wiersz.className = "PracaOrange";
```

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener('click', dodajWiersz);

var lp = 1;

 function dodajWiersz() {
    var wiersz = document.createElement("tr");

     var liczba = document.createElement("td");
     liczba.innerHTML = lp;

     var imie = document.createElement("td");
     var val2 = document.getElementById("imie").value;
     imie.innerHTML = val2;

     var nazwisko = document.createElement("td");
     var val3 = document.getElementById("nazwisko").value;
     nazwisko.innerHTML = val3;

     var email = document.createElement("td");
     var val4 = document.getElementById("email").value;
     email.innerHTML = val4;

     var wiek = document.createElement("td");
     var val5 = document.getElementById("wiek").value;
     wiek.innerHTML = val5;

     var data = document.createElement("td");
     var val6 = document.getElementById("data").value;
     data.innerHTML = val6;

     var plec = document.createElement("td");
     var val7 = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
     plec.innerHTML = val7;

     var grupa = document.createElement("td");
     var val8 = document.getElementById("grupa").value;
     grupa.innerHTML = val8;
        switch(val8) {
            case "Rodzina":
                wiersz.classList.add("RodzinaZielony");
                break;
            case 'Praca':
                wiersz.classList.add("PracaOrange");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } 

     wiersz.appendChild(liczba);
     wiersz.appendChild(imie);
     wiersz.appendChild(nazwisko);
     wiersz.appendChild(email);
     wiersz.appendChild(wiek);
     wiersz.appendChild(data);
     wiersz.appendChild(plec);
     wiersz.appendChild(grupa);

     var dodac = document.getElementById("tbd");
     dodac.appendChild(wiersz);
     lp = lp + 1;
 }
```

```css
tr.RodzinaZielony {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

tr.PracaOrange {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<table id="customersKontakty">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Liczba porządkowa</th>
       <th>Imię</th>
       <th>Nazwisko</th>
       <th>Email</th>
       <th>Wiek</th>
       <th>Data urodzenia</th>
       <th>Płeć</th>
       <th>Grupa</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbd">

  </tbody>
</table>
<element class="plabel">
  <br><br><br>
  <p class="plabell">Imię:<p><input type="text" id="imie"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Nazwisko:<p><input type="text" id="nazwisko"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Email:<p><input type="email" id="email"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Wiek:<p><input type="number" id="wiek"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Data urodzenia:<p><input type="date" id="data"></p></p>
  <p class="plabell">Płeć:
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mężczyzna"> Mężczyzna
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Kobieta"> Kobieta
    </p>
  </p>
  <p class="plabell">Grupa:
    <p>
      <select id="grupa">
        <option value="Rodzina">Rodzina</option>
        <option value="Przyjaciele">Przyjaciele</option>
        <option value="Praca">Praca</option>
        <option value="Znajomi">Znajomi</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </p>
</element>
<p align="center"><input type="button" value="Dodaj osobę" id="myBtn"></p>
```

Comment: Но все же className можно использовать, значит в том случаем когда стили пишут не в файле.css, а в файле.html в элементе <style></style>, так получается?

Comment: А причем тут стили? Их где угодно писать можно и будет работать что через className, что через classList. В ответе оперировал сугубо своим мнением.